# Logical expressions in C

Tags: c

Why is the result "3: 1 0 0 4", when we have incremented x?
Why isn't it "3: 1 1 0 4"?

```
   x=0;y=4;z=3;
   printf("3: %d  %d %d %d\n", ++x || !y, x&&y, !z, y);
```

Comment: Because `0` and anything is `0`.

Comment: Undefined behaviour.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen it is?  can you explain that please?  It looks ok

Comment: @Tibrogargan In C it is not defined which order the arguments will be evaluated. Therefore the `x++` may happen before or after the `&&`

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Could you eliminate the issue with parentheses?  i.e.  `printf("3: %d  %d %d %d\n", (++x || !y), x&&y, (!z), y); `  (Yes, still unordered but there's a sequence point before the actual call and these are independent modifications)

Comment: @Tibrogargan No, parens wouldn't change anything. The sequence is still undefined and the only thing you can do is to make them into separate statements, e.g. by using variables.

Comment: @Tibrogargan: I'm afraid the parentheses do not change anything, there is no sequence point between the argument evaluations. Even using the comma operator does not fix the issue.

Comment: @chqrlie yep, but that's not a comma operator

Comment: @Tibrogargan: no it is not, but **even** if one used the comma operator in the argument expression, such as `printf("3: %d %d %d %d\n", (0, ++x || !y), x && y, (!z), y);` The order of evaluation would still be indeterminate, and the behavior undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you compile this with `cc` you'll get the warning:

```
warning: unsequenced modification and access to 'x' [-Wunsequenced]`
```

Modifying a variable and accessing it elsewhere within `printf` is undefined behavior and will not give a logical result, nor the same result on every compiler.

Answer (score 3):

```
printf("3: %d  %d %d %d\n", ++x || !y, x&&y, !z, y);
```

`++x` is evaluated before `!y` because of the `||`.  `!y` is only evaluated if `++x` result was 0.

But there is no specified order to `++x || !y` vs. `x&&y` evaluation.  Code lacks a *sequence point*.

Answer (score 0):

As @Sami mentioned in his comment, the order that the arguments gets evaluated is compiler-specific and probably depends on calling convention. In your case the `x && y` argument gets computed first before the `++x || !y`.

Comment: Will the order of the arguments matter in this case?  From @EliSadoff's comment - `0` && anything is `0`

Comment: Order of A and B in A && B won't matter because of operator precedence. For example the ++ and ! operators have higher precedence than || so will always be evaluated first

Comment: Yes, that's obvious (and quite helpful - I wish the OP had asked about that instead).  This still does not answer the actual question - (Eli's comment is really the answer)